# PDO Riddle (No while loop)

Tags: pdo

I just recently learned how to work with PDO database queries, but my latest query isn't working for some reason. All my other queries include arrays and while loops, but I don't think this one requires either, so I may just need to change the query structure somehow.

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT H.N, H.URL, H.Title, H.Subtitle,
 H.Site, H.MetaTitle, H.MetaDesc, H.KW, H.Live, A.Article, A.Pagedex
 FROM 1_home_pages H
 LEFT JOIN 1_home_articles A ON A.Site = H.Site
 WHERE H.URL = :MySection AND H.Site = :MySiteId AND H.Live = 1 AND A.Site = :MySiteId AND        A.Section = :MySection");

// $stm->execute();
$stm->execute(array(
 'MySiteId'=>$MySiteID,
 'MySection'=>$MySection
));
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

I added the line $data = $stm->fetchAll();, and it now works - as an array. The foreach statement below displays EVERYTHING in one jumbled mess...

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    print_r($row); 
}
```

To escape the array and just display one item at a time, I tried the following:

```
$Content = $data['Article'];
echo $Content;
```

But it doesn't display anything. Can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you made a typo while posting this question, or this is a typo from your source code: you have :MySection and yet while executing you write MySection (without colon). What's more, this line:

```
WHERE H.URL = :MySection 
  AND H.Site = :MySiteId 
  AND H.Live = 1 
  AND A.Site = :MySiteId 
  AND A.Section = :MySection");
```

You used multiple parameters with same name in one statement. Don't know if this is a correct way to do it, since I've never done it. I suggest you try using different names for parameters and see if that helps. Also, what do you mean 'but my latest query isn't working for some reason.' ? What does it return? Does it return anything at all? fetchAll returns **multiple** rows, that's why you get array.

Instead of `$data = $stm->fetchAll();` use `$data = $stm->fetch();`. It will return next row from your query.